# Compile errors when accessing a structure element using stringified name

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, stringify

I'm trying to construct a bunch of functions which access elements of a structure.  I'm using the # stringify preprocessor directives to construct function names ending in the element name, and inside those function access the element.  This will allow calling a bunch of simple macros to create some very similar functions.

When compiling the following simplified example, I get a compiler error

```
struct test
{
    float tst;
}test;

// Macro that creates callback functions
#define test_float_(varname) \
void test_float_##varname(void) {\
    test.#varname = 0;\
}

test_float_(tst)
```

> ```
> error: expected identifier before string constant
>  test_float_(tst)
>                 ^
> ../protocol.c:66:8: note: in definition of macro 'test_float_'
>   test.#varname = 0;\
> ```

If I remove the `test.#varname = 0;` line, then the error goes away.
What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Just make it `test.varname`, drop the `#`. As written, the macro expands to to `test."tst"` which is meaningless, and so the compiler complains.

Comment: I'm using c, not c++.  I need to make 12 callback functions that are only different in the variables they access, and function name.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`# MacroArgument` creates a string literal out of a macro argument.

Your code:

```
struct test
{
    float tst;
}test;

// Macro that creates callback functions
#define test_float_(varname) \
void test_float_##varname(void) {\
    test.#varname = 0;\
}

test_float_(tst)
```

preprocesses to (https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/ZkaKaA):

```
struct test
{
    float tst;
}test;

void test_float_tst(void) { test."tst" = 0;}
```

The `test."tst" = 0;` part is obviously a syntax error. Lose the `#` before `varname` and it'll work.

(Note: The `-E` flag given to a POSIX C compiler causes it to just run the preprocessor, textually. You'll find it useful in debugging C macros.)